# Google Sheets - I can't seem to make tow cell with the same time actually equal eachother

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data in Column A on the Manifest sheet which is a list of Names, in Column C is a list of appointment times, this information is a pulled via a query from the Master sheet.  I then have a list of available appointment times in Column G. I want to see how many people are booked in for an appointment at certain times.

when I look at the times in the cells they look the same but when I look at them as numbers they are slightly different.  I have changed the times to numbers and rounded them in columns D and F and tried comparing them but they still do not seem to match.

I am using this formula

=transpose(FILTER($A$8:$A,$D$8:$D<F10,$A$8:$A,$D$8:$D>=F9))

Which I think is checking for people who have appointments at 08:35 eg less than 08:40 and greater than or equal to 08:35.
It returns N/A even though there is a person with an appointment at 08:35.  I have tried the formula referencing the time columns and the number columns and neither seem to work.

The problem seems to be that when I look at the times as numbers they are slightly different.  No matter what format I apply.

Here is a link to the file
[Appointments](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1020bQIaKJ4EwqvtBxteoEfBEW4l7bfom_aFPfnfYWs0/copy)

Comment: It seems that contributor "JohnA" has provided you with a formula that meets your immediate need. However, in looking at your spreadsheet (after making a copy), there is a LOT of inefficiency and "clunky" functionality, which means there is quite a bit of room for streamlining and making your life easier. If this interests you, create a link to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it), being sure to set the link's permissions at creation time to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." Comment here. Then I'll take a look and illustrate some suggestions on the sheet. Otherwise, best of luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the QUERY() function and got it to work with this formula:

```
=IFNA(query(A7:C, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE hour(C) =  "&HOUR(G8)&" AND minute(C) = "&MINUTE(G8)&" LABEL COUNT(A) ''",1),0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great.  Thank you so much.  I also much prefer a Query but did not know how to do it.  I have added another query using your original one to show me the names of the people at the appointment time.   =IFNA(transpose(query($A$8:$C, "SELECT A WHERE hour(C) = "&HOUR(G8)&" AND minute(C) = "&MINUTE(G8)&" ",0)),0).  Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Nice! QUERY() is powerful but one must be prepared to debug the 2nd parameter as string building can get hairy. :-)

Comment: OH, I'll look out for that, thank you again.  In the last week, I have had a few queries which when returning N/A have not cleared all of the cells.  This is very strange and is only happening on a few of my queries. Interestingly the blocked data doesn't seem to strop the query repopulating again.  Have you had anything like this happen?

Comment: N/A means no results found which is why I wrapped the QUERY() in IFNA()

Comment: Thank you, I know that but what I mean is usually all cells below the N/A are cleared but in some queries this is not happening.